# Using tcolorbox, but the color is not exactly the right color

Tags: color, tcolorbox, adjustbox, colorbox, box

I am using the following code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\newtcolorbox{tbox}[3][]
{
    colframe = #2!25,
    colback  = #2!10,
    coltitle = #2!20!black,  
    title    = {#3},
    #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tbox}{yellow}{contain something}
    The color is around ``contain sometihng" is not yellow 
\end{tbox} 
\end{document}
```

However, I noticed the following problem

[image]

The color in the header seem not be yellow enough. It is "sandy".

Similar for red.

[image]

Again, this is not what "red" usually is if you were to type something like "{\color{red} text}. This is more like a pink or flesh color.

Can anyone suggest how I can change the code so the color are more genuine?

Comment: Welcome! You understand the `!25` makes the color only 25% yellow (or red) and the rest white? Did you try dropping the `!25` after `#2`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat NO idea. I copied the code from someone. Actually the code is quite mysterious if you can explain it I will ACCEPT your answer anD upvote!!

Comment: Try `\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\newtcolorbox{tbox}[3][]
{
    colframe = #2,
    colback  = #2!10,
    coltitle = #2!20!black,  
    title    = {#3},
    #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tbox}{yellow}{contain something}
    The color of the frame is a yellow yellow.
\end{tbox} 
\begin{tbox}{red}{contain something}
    The color of the frame is a red red.
\end{tbox} 
\end{document}`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat much better, thank you !!! Schrodinger Scat

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Please answer formally the question already solved, so it can be removed form the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the color of the frame, which is controlled by the key `colframe`, is set to `#2!25`. Here `#2` is the first "main" argument, i.e. the color you set in `\begin{tbox}{<color>}{...`.  As usual in the packages using `xcolor`, like `tcolorbox`, an exclamation mark indicates color mixing. So if you have `<color A>!<percentage>!<color B>`, this is a mix of `<percentage>` % of `<color A>` and the remaining `100-<percentage>` % of `<color B>`. E.g. `red!25!blue` is 25% red and the remaining 75% blue. If there is no second color specified, the second color is taken to be white. That is, e.g. `red!25` is the same as `red!25!white`, which is the "sandy red" you are seeing, and likewise for yellow. So in order to get "full" yellow and red colors in the frame, you need to drop the `!25`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\newtcolorbox{tbox}[3][]{%
colframe=#2,colback=#2!10,coltitle=#2!20!black,title={#3},#1}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tbox}{yellow}{contain something} 
The color of the frame is a yellow yellow. 
\end{tbox} 
\begin{tbox}{red}{contain something} 
The color of the frame is a red red. 
\end{tbox} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

More details can be found in the `xcolor` manual (`texdoc xcolor`). BTW, `tcolorbox` loads `xcolor`, so you do not need to load it separately.